# Are arrays of 'structs' theoretically possible in Java?

Tags: java, memory, jvm, memory-efficient

There are cases when one needs a memory efficient to store lots of objects. To do that in Java you are forced to use several primitive arrays (see below why) or a big byte array which produces a bit CPU overhead for converting.

Example: you have a `class Point { float x; float y;}`. Now you want to store N points in an array which would take at least N * 8 bytes for the floats and N * 4 bytes for the reference on a 32bit JVM. So at least 1/3 is garbage (not counting in the normal object overhead here). But if you would store this in two float arrays all would be fine.

**My question**: Why does Java not optimize the memory usage for arrays of references? I mean why not directly embed the object in the array like it is done in C++?

E.g. marking the class Point final should be sufficient for the JVM to see the maximum length of the data for the Point class. Or where would this be against [the specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/arrays.html)? Also this would save a lot of memory when handling large n-dimensional matrices etc

**Update**:

I would like to know wether the JVM could theoretically optimize it (e.g. behind the scene) and under which conditions - not wether I can force the JVM somehow. I think the second point of the conclusion is the reason it cannot be done easily if at all.

Conclusions what the JVM would need to know:

1. The class needs to be final to let the JVM guess the length of one array entry
2. The array needs to be read only. Of course you can change the values like `Point p = arr[i]; p.setX(i)` but you cannot write to the array via `inlineArr[i] = new Point()`. Or the JVM would have to introduce copy semantics which would be against the "Java way". See aroth's answer
3. How to initialize the array (calling default constructor or leaving the members intialized to their default values)

Comment: The first problem I see is that you can't really store a null reference...unless you spend another chunk o' memory on a bit vector for null versus non-null references.

Comment: hmmh valid concern. but you could reserve one bit per entry for it or all values are initialized to defaults (floats get 0, boolean gets false, references get null etc) or call the default constructor N times etc

Comment: I found a simple approach for Java: code generation from annotated objects! and the framework then creates a wrapper class for that object. See this example https://github.com/carrotsearch/hppc/blob/structs/hppc-examples/src/main/java/com/carrotsearch/hppc/examples/StructExample.java and BattleshipsCell.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scenario you describe might save on memory (though in practice I'm not sure it would even do that), but it probably would add a fair bit of computational overhead when actually placing an object into an array.  Consider that when you do `new Point()` the object you create is dynamically allocated on the heap.  So if you allocate 100 `Point` instances by calling `new Point()` there is no guarantee that their locations will be contiguous in memory (and in fact they will most likely not be allocated to a contiguous block of memory).

So how would a `Point` instance actually make it into the "compressed" array?  It seems to me that Java would have to explicitly copy *every* field in `Point` into the contiguous block of memory that was allocated for the array.  That could become costly for object types that have many fields.  Not only that, but the original `Point` instance is still taking up space on the heap, as well as inside of the array.  So unless it gets immediately garbage-collected (I suppose any references could be rewritten to point at the copy that was placed in the array, thereby theoretically allowing immediate garbage-collection of the original instance) you're actually using more storage than you would be if you had just stored the reference in the array.

Moreover, what if you have multiple "compressed" arrays and a mutable object type?  Inserting an object into an array necessarily copies that object's fields into the array.  So if you do something like:

```
Point p = new Point(0, 0);
Point[] compressedA = {p};  //assuming 'p' is "optimally" stored as {0,0}
Point[] compressedB = {p};  //assuming 'p' is "optimally" stored as {0,0}

compressedA[0].setX(5)  
compressedB[0].setX(1)  

System.out.println(p.x);
System.out.println(compressedA[0].x);
System.out.println(compressedB[0].x);
```

...you would get:

```
0
5
1
```

...even though logically there should only be a single instance of `Point`.  Storing references avoids this kind of problem, and also means that in any case where a nontrivial object is being shared between multiple arrays your total storage usage is probably *lower* than it would be if each array stored a copy of all of that object's fields.

Comment: "though in practice I'm not sure it would even do that" why??

Comment: "copy every field in Point" well, please reread the question. I would like to avoid copying etc. just using the raw bytes from the array to handle object members as it is done in C++

Comment: Your last conclusion makes sense. These are copy semantics from C++ unlike in Java ...

Comment: One could avoid having copy semantics if the array is read only

Comment: @Karussell - I'm not sure it would help because of how the `Point` objects would usually be allocated.  In the case where you do `Point[] x = new Point[100]` and then use *only* the `Point` instances that come pre-packed in the array I can see total memory usage being reduced.  But as soon as you start doing things like `Point p = new Point(0,0);` and `x[0] = p;` you're actually using *more* space, because you have storage for `p` (8 bytes) and then repeated storage for `x[0]` (8 bytes), *unless* writing `p` into the array makes `p` point at the array's copy and reclaims the original `p`.

Comment: The semantics of copying the coordinates from Point objects would indeed be different from those of storing references to Point objects, but sometimes that's precisely what's required.  Suppose, for example, a DisplayThing is supposed to show a bunch of icons at various coordinates.  If it were given the coordinates for an icon in a Point object, and stored a reference the Point it was given in an array.  What would happen if some outside code altered that Point?

Comment: "but sometimes that's precisely what's required" -> IMO different semantics won't go into core Java 'only' for the purpose of memory tuning or similar

Answer (score 3):

Java doesn't provide a way to do this because it's not a language-level choice to make.  C, C++, and the like expose ways to do this because they are system-level programming languages where you are expected to know system-level features and make decisions based on the specific architecture that you are using.

In Java, you are targeting the JVM.  The JVM doesn't specify whether or not this is permissible (I'm making an assumption that this is true; I haven't combed the JLS thoroughly to prove that I'm right here).  The idea is that when you write Java code, you trust the JIT to make intelligent decisions.  That is where the reference types could be folded into an array or the like.  So the "Java way" here would be that you cannot specify if it happens or not, but if the JIT can make that optimization and improve performance it could and should.

I am not sure whether this optimization in particular is implemented, but I do know that similar ones are:  for example, objects allocated with `new` are conceptually on the "heap", but if the JVM notices (through a technique called escape analysis) that the object is method-local it can allocate the fields of the object on the stack or even directly in CPU registers, removing the "heap allocation" overhead entirely with no language change.

**Update for updated question**

If the question is "can this be done at all", I think the answer is yes.  There are a few corner cases (such as null pointers) but you should be able to work around them.  For null references, the JVM could convince itself that there will never be null elements, or keep a bit vector as mentioned previously.  Both of these techniques would likely be predicated on escape analysis showing that the array reference never leaves the method, as I can see the bookkeeping becoming tricky if you try to e.g. store it in an object field.

Comment: Well, I'm more after if it is theoretically possible + some points to docs

Comment: At the moment I don't think this optimization is possible for the JVM

Comment: Theoretically?  Sounds like it is.  But I think you're right, it's not something done currently.

Comment: No I don't think it is possible in theory. Have a look at my conclusions

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this tantamount to providing trivial classes such as the following?

```
class Fixed {
   float hiddenArr[];
   Point pointArray(int position) {
      return new Point(hiddenArr[position*2], hiddenArr[position*2+1]);
   }
}
```

Also, it's possible to implement this without making the programmer explicitly state that they'd like it; the JVM is already aware of "value types" (POD types in C++); ones with only other plain-old-data types inside them.  I believe HotSpot uses this information during stack elision, no reason it couldn't do it for arrays too?

Comment: But consider how much memory you're unnecessarily churning through by creating a new `Point` instance for every array access.  CPU time too, if the `Point` constructor happens to do anything nontrivial.

Comment: well not really. new Point will consume more space. what if you iterate through all points or use them frequently etc? then you don't have the benefits. are value types primitive types?

Comment: I'm *reasonably* sure the JVM will already avoid that allocation by using the stack, assuming you're immediately using the returned value.  That's its job, after all.  I don't have a debug JVM to hand to prove it to you, though.

Comment: Additional problems: you now have the issue that `pointArray[i] != pointArray[i]`, since you're allocating a new object each time.  The difficulties pile up.

Comment: A hint to the JIT that you want your objects inline is possible, but I strongly suspect that the Java authors would rather fall on their sword than add an additional operator overload (on ==) to the language, as much as I'd like that to be the case.

Comment: I would think it better to have a mutable point type and have a method copy the coordinates of the indexed point into a passed-in pre-existing instance.  That would help make clear that the point object in question was not "attached" to the array.